# Changing the default parameter for Parse.User.logIn() to emailid instead of username

Tags: parse-platform

```
var usrnm = "admin";
var pwd = "admin123";

Parse.User.logIn(usrnm,pwd, {
      success: function(user) {},
      error: function(user, error) {
        // The login failed. Check error to see why.
        alert("Invalid username or Password");
      }
    });
```

Username and password in the User table are the default values which the, parse will check while logging into the system using this code `Parse.User.logIn()`  . I want to change username to emailid field in the User table , how do i do that?

```
var emaild = "admin";
var pwd = "admin123";

Parse.User.logIn(emaild,pwd, {
      success: function(user) {},
      error: function(user, error) {
        // The login failed. Check error to see why.
        alert("Invalid username or Password");
      }
    });
```

The above code checks for the emaild with the username field in the User table, whereas i need to check it with the emailid field in the User table.

How can i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have done this by setting the var emailId = "admin@domain.com",
and in database set the value of the username to the emailIDs.